# Read sqlite3 table with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am simply trying to console.log() rows that each have an automatically incremented integer as their primary key. What is the most efficient way to do this in Node.js? My database file, at least for now, consists of one table with a few rows that I need to access. I am very new to sqlite3 and have tried to log

```
db.run('SELECT * FROM "talon"')
```

which returns

```
Database { open: false, filename: 'bin/data.db', mode: 65542 }
```

Clearly I've not much of an idea what I'm doing, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [a sqlite-nodejs tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)

Comment: @gato wow I really didn’t search as hard as I thought. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.JS, I/O happens asynchronously.  This means that `db.run` will return execution flow before the DB results are fetched.  You will need to provide a **callback** in order to read the results:

```
// note, that I changed the call to use "each"
db.each('SELECT * FROM "talon"', function(err, row) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(row)
})
```

I have not tried this code, but I gathered the API details from [this link](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API).